# How to avoid IE11 from interpretting and displaying special charaters as foriegn language

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, encoding, character-encoding

I have a webpage in english and the web browser IE11 rendering it.But the settings under `View -> Encoding` is always say `Korean`.Which is my intended setting.

Now in the page a text like `"bypass"` is displayed as `밷ypass�`, that clearly says ,special characters are rather treated differently with this setting.

Any suggestion/help on correcting this, maintaining the settings under `View` would be appreciated.

The behavior is similar in Chrome, so not browser specific is what i believe.

Comment: Why are you using `Korean` and not `Unicode (UTF-8)` which is what most web pages should be encoded as? Besides, you should not need to set a fixed encoding in your browser. There are HTTP headers and `<meta>` tags for that, *those* should indicate encoding. The IE setting is called `Auto-Select`.

Comment: Thanks  @MDeSchaepmeester . Now my concern is, what if the target machine has a foreign language [chinese,korean, etc]  OS and the `Auto-Select` IE renders a page with text like `밷ypass�` ? Is there a way i can control this with `<meta>` tags ? any pointers would be of help.

Comment: <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> `    just to add to it ,i see the above in my html page, saying it's  utf-8 encoding.So not very sure why the special chars are interpretted wrongly.

Comment: How do those characters appear in your HTML source exactly? You should code them as `&quot;`.

Comment: Thank you @MDeSchaepmeester , i figured it. My bad !. The editer i was using was the culprit. I used Eclipse with a different text encoding set other than UTF-8, changing this worked !!.                                                           `Preferences >> General >> Editors >> Text editors >> Spelling: Enconding`